Force an app to use current console session/stdout under Windows
I have an app that spawns its own console Windows/stdout, no matter what. is there some hack I can use to force it to output into current console stdout?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Check the documentation, there might be some optional way to start the app.
Besides that; the alternative that remains; somehow you need to change the software file to not contain the code that creates the separate Window.

Notably:

If it is an open source app, then you might have access to the source
code; having the required knowledge about changing the code and then
compiling your own version you may well be able to create e.g. a bypass
option.
If that isn't the case, what remains as an option: using a debugger to locate the code, and then poking bytes (hex digits) into the correct places - to change the behavior.
[this requires a good bit of knowledge about software on the platform you're using.]

